# Installing libraries for arm-gcc-compiler

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I have a functional arm cross compiler that I can use with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc command.

This works for simple programs but I run into problems when I have to compile bigger programs requiring libraries like x11, opengl as the required headers/files are not present in arm-linux-gnuebi directory but in normal gcc compiler.

I need to know, is there any easy way to install such libraries for arm-gcc.

Using simple apt-get does'nt work. For example, if I need freeglut3-dev for cross compiling an application, how would I do it.

Can I configure apt-get do install libraries for arm-gcc ? Or can I use gdebi to install .deb(those with arm support) on my own host computer that will work ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this page, there is an option in apt to specify the package architecture:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115272/download-package-via-apt-for-another-architecture

An example for architecture ":armhf" on a beagleboard is here:
See section "Qt build with X"
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Embedding/IPCLiteAPI_BeagleBoardHF

An alternative would be to create a VM for development:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Virtual_ARM_Linux_environment

I hope it helps
ssinfod